# To to set text of checkbox inside repeater

Tags: asp.net, html, checkbox, webforms, repeater

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Text="<%#Container.DataItem('Text')%>" />  
        </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

How do I get Text to be set from the bound field (which is also called Text)? I tried many ways like Val("") but it always says an error.

For the example above it says : Compiler Error Message: CS1012: Too many characters in character literal.

If I change it to `<asp:CheckBox runat="server" Text="<%#Container.DataItem("Text")%>" />`     -- it says : Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Text")%>' />  
    </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

When binding values inside a repeater, you need to use single-quotes.

Instead of..

`Text="<%#Container.DataItem('Text')%>"`

...try...

`Text='<%#Container.DataItem("Text")%>'`

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server">(String)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text")</asp:CheckBox>
```